# cant pass param through link_to (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a problem with passing params. in show view i have

> =link_to "Send message", {:controller => "users", :action =>
>   "send_message", :user_id => @user.id}

and my users_controller have method

```
def send_message
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @message=Message.new
    redirect_to send_message_path
end
```

and my show method

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post=Post.new
    @posts=@user.posts.reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10)  
  end
```

but i have and error after clicking on link

> Couldn't find User without an ID

in that line, in send_message method

```
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

what i am doing wrong? i read a lot examples about this , but it doesnt work(

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=link_to "Send message", [:send_message, @user]
```

and in your routes:

```
resources :users do
  post :send_message, :on => :collection
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to change :user_id to :id, like this

```
=link_to "Send message", {:controller => "users", :action => "send_message", :id => @user.id}

def send_message
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @message=Message.new
    redirect_to send_message_path
end
```

If that works it's because your route isn't set up to use a :user_id param. If it doesn't it would help to know more about your route.

Comment: i have same error when using :id <br>my route is  match '/send_message', :to =>'users#send_message'

Comment: ahhh it worked when i changed my route to match '/users/:id/send_message', :to =>'users#send_message' , :as =>'send_message'. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: If you want it to work in a way similar to what you already have you should be able to change your route to `match 'users/:id/send_message', :to =>'users#send_message'`. If you want to change things to a more elegant solution, see fl00r's example.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you should write:

```
resources :users do
  post :send_message, :on => :member
end
```

And in your view you write:

```
= link_to "Send Message", send_message_user_path(@user)
```

This will use `id` instead of `user_id`.
So in your controller you need to use `params[:id]` as well.

Imho this is cleaner than @fl00r solution, because it is a member method, not a collection.

But I am a bit confused as to why you would have that method inside the controller at all.
Because the only thing it does is redirect to the `send_message_path` anyway. The instance variables you set are all lost then. So instead in your view write this:

```
= link_to 'Send message', send_message_path(:user_id => @user.id)
```

And this will send you to the correct controller straightaway (where you will have to retrieve the user).

Also your `show` method could use some work: you should define a `has_many :posts` in your `User` model.